# When creating a DOC or Excel file using the LUA language, Russian characters are not displayed correctly

Tags: excel, lua, doc

My code works, but instead of Russian characters incomprehensible characters are displayed. My code:

```
local fileName = "myfile3.doc" 
local FileWrite 
FileWrite = io.open(fileName, "w") 
FileWrite:write("фывф", '\n') 
FileWrite:close()
```

or

```
require('luacom') 
excel = luacom.CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
excel.Visible = true 
wb = excel.Workbooks:Add() 
ws = wb.Worksheets(1) 
for i=1, 10 do 
ws.Cells(i,1).Value2 = "фывф" 
end
```

Comment: You should convert Russian string to Lua binary string for the encoding expected by the destination system (simple file should be in Win1251, and probably luacom objects are expected text in UTF-16LE, I don't know for sure, read the docs)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me exactly as written. I used UTF-8 encoding for the file (CP65001 on Win8). Here is the snapshot of the result:

[image: Excel screenshot of script result]